# how to decrease border size to fit a div

Tags: html

My question is, how to reduce the border size so to fit the `div`, so it's consists of a `h5`, `hr` and 2 `p` elements?

```html
<div style="border:  black 0.5px solid ; align-self: start;">
  <h5 style="margin-left: 450px;margin-top: 200px;">xxxx</h5>
  <hr width="50px" style="margin-left: 4px;" />
  <p style="margin-left: 450px;margin-top: 40px;">xxxx</p>
  <p style="margin-left: 450px;margin-top: 10px;">xxxx</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Start with valid HTML. I added a  <!doctype html>, a </head> a </h5> and swapped the slash in the <hr/>

Comment: What do you mean by border size? You want the div to be smaller or the border to be thicker?

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like the border to fit only around the div ,the code that i gave when it runs it fits around the whole section

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove padding and margin sets by browser

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

add it below  inside HERE! 
and it will decrease border size to fit a the page so you can work on the div

Comment: i would like the border to fit around the div and the elements

Comment: You have to specify the size of the width and height like it to fit around the div and the elements